# Connecting MSSQLS to PHP site on Windows/IIS

Tags: php

First experience with SQL/in-house server, have searched thoroughly for answer.

Trying to call database using code below:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('dbname');
echo '1';
if ($conn === false){
    die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
echo "Successfully connected!";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Get error saying the extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server.

Went to link, installed driver. (May not have installed in right location, not sure). It seems to me that I have everything else installed correctly.

Relevant snips from phpinfo

[image: link1]
[image: link2]

-php v7, x64

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How I get my data to display and not get an error?